# Extract tar.gz files into a directory with different basename based on their match in the text file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, tar

I have hundred of folders, some with with tar.gz files and some with bam files. I just wanted to extract tar.gz files into a different directory. Folders with tar.gz files looks like mentioned below:

```
d1017f74-3a39-4427-af57-273e34247b49
           ├──--- UNCID_2207021.7b9569bc-f513-4b64-9a7c-7bb53b9be79b.110801_UNC12-SN629_0115_BD0DVEABXX_3_ACAGTG.tar.gz
5e2d5c52-596f-49bc-967c-42129abbacbf
           ├──--- UNCID_2208720.71b58051-3bf8-4dfb-a431-c8aceab7c799.110608_UNC13-SN749_0073_BD0CV8ABXX_2.tar.gz
2ef74f93-5da2-454c-aca2-d86c289eacb8
           ├──--- UNCID_2206802.25be50e7-7705-492d-a44a-0e40180d10c8.110901_UNC12-SN629_0127_BC025UABXX_1_CTTGTA.tar.gz
e01ca3e0-beb0-46b7-bb7c-f5b16f966918
           ├──--- UNCID_2521679.d817dcee-1322-4949-a6e9-138447e6fc56.140417_UNC13-SN749_0343_BC41HBACXX_5_CTTGTA.tar.gz
992a7083-28ce-4857-898e-9d4b4fbf2fa1
           ├──--- UNCID_2319278.bf92b8cc-9a5c-4e96-917c-c264fe588f8d.131118_UNC12-SN629_0336_AC31D0ACXX_5_ACTTGA.tar.gz
```

For extracting tar.gz files into a target directory I have used following command:

```
find /path/to/directory -name '*.tar.gz' -execdir tar -C /path/to/targetdirectory -xzvf '{}' \;
```

This command gives output fastq files for some tar.gz files with names like below:

```
110801_UNC12-SN629_0115_BD0DVEABXX.3_1.fastq
110801_UNC12-SN629_0115_BD0DVEABXX.3_2.fastq

110608_UNC13-SN749_0073_BD0CV8ABXX.2_1.fastq
110608_UNC13-SN749_0073_BD0CV8ABXX.2_2.fastq

110901_UNC12-SN629_0127_BC025UABXX.1_1.fastq
110901_UNC12-SN629_0127_BC025UABXX.1_2.fastq
```

This is not what I want. There is a text file with Foldernames, tar.gz file names, sample names like following:

```
FolderNames                                         Tar.gz files                                                                                 SampleNames
d1017f74-3a39-4427-af57-273e34247b49    UNCID_2207021.7b9569bc-f513-4b64-9a7c-7bb53b9be79b.110801_UNC12-SN629_0115_BD0DVEABXX_3_ACAGTG.tar.gz   S-E9-A1NA-11A
5e2d5c52-596f-49bc-967c-42129abbacbf    UNCID_2208720.71b58051-3bf8-4dfb-a431-c8aceab7c799.110608_UNC13-SN749_0073_BD0CV8ABXX_2.tar.gz    S-AO-A12H-01A
2ef74f93-5da2-454c-aca2-d86c289eacb8    UNCID_2206802.25be50e7-7705-492d-a44a-0e40180d10c8.110901_UNC12-SN629_0127_BC025UABXX_1_CTTGTA.tar.gz   S-AC-A23E-01A
e01ca3e0-beb0-46b7-bb7c-f5b16f966918    UNCID_2521679.d817dcee-1322-4949-a6e9-138447e6fc56.140417_UNC13-SN749_0343_BC41HBACXX_5_CTTGTA.tar.gz   S-C8-A8HR-01A
992a7083-28ce-4857-898e-9d4b4fbf2fa1    UNCID_2319278.bf92b8cc-9a5c-4e96-917c-c264fe588f8d.131118_UNC12-SN629_0336_AC31D0ACXX_5_ACTTGA.tar.gz   S-A8-A08A-01A
```

Output should get sample name from text file and should look like below:

```
S-E9-A1NA-11A.3_1.fastq
S-E9-A1NA-11A.3_2.fastq

S-AO-A12H-01A.2_1.fastq
S-AO-A12H-01A.2_2.fastq

S-AC-A23E-01A.1_1.fastq
S-AC-A23E-01A.1_2.fastq

S-C8-A8HR-01A.5_1.fastq
S-C8-A8HR-01A.5_2.fastq

S-A8-A08A-01A.5_1.fastq
S-A8-A08A-01A.5_2.fastq
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this then?

```
while read -r folder tarfile sample; do
  find /path/to/directory/"$folder" -name "$tarfile" -execdir sh -c '
        tar -C /path/to/targetdirectory -xzvf "$0";
        for f in *.fastq; do
            mv "$f" "$1.${f#*.}";
        done' {} "$sample" \;
done <Foldernames
```

I'm not altogether sure you need `find` here at all, but your exposition doesn't reveal what exactly `/path/to` and its subdirectories refers to, so I assume you know what you are doing there (or how to stop doing that if you don't).

Comment: From tar.gz file I directly need fastq's with sample names as output. And in your code where did u mention about text file?

Comment: I assumed you have a file named `Foldernames`. This renames the extracted `fastq` files like you requested.

Comment: Ok. Could you please tell what does "$1.${f#*.}" mean?

Comment: `"$sample"` is passed in as `$1`. The parameter substitution `${f#*.}` obtains the value of `$f` with the beginning of the string up through the first dot is trimmed off. (If there are no dots, no trimming will occur.)

Comment: This is the error I got. find: ‘0027045b-9ed6-45af-a68e-f55037b5184c,UNCID_2210188.c71ca9f7-248f-460c-b5d3-afb2c648fef2.110412_UNC13-SN749_0051_AB0168ABXX_4.tar.gz,S-B6-A0I8-01A\r’: No such file or directory

Comment: The `\r` is an indication that your file has DOS line feeds. `tr -d '\015' <file | while read`... or fix the input file once and for all with `dos2unix`; or stop editing files on Windows (or get a decent editor which lets you configure it for Unix files if you can't get rid of Windows completely).

Comment: I work on Mac...is it still dos2unix?

Comment: It's not a utility which is installed by default, but you can install it with Homebrew, or just use `tr`. More options are easily googlable; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640902/remove-r-cr-from-csv